# Unable to test SPI interface

Tags: raspbian, spi

I followed the instructions given in the blog and everything got executed without any errors. But in the end

[Link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#spi-overview)

Ran this script:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/linux/rpi-3.10.y/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c
gcc -o spidev_test spidev_test.c
./spidev_test -D /dev/spidev0.0
```

Expected output:

```
spi mode: 0
bits per word: 8
max speed: 500000 Hz (500 KHz)

FF FF FF FF FF FF
40 00 00 00 00 95
FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF
DE AD BE EF BA AD
F0 0D
```

Output which I got:

```
spi mode: 0
bits per word: 8
max speed: 500000 Hz (500 KHz)

00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00
```

I did connect MOSI and MISO.
Also lsmod does show spibcm2708 drivers being enabled.

I tested the same tutorial on 2 Raspberry Pi, but same result. Where am I going wrong? What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

Error fixed. Thanks to @dastaan for spotting.
I was using a 26 pin reference and hence was doing a wrong connection. It's working fine for me now.

Comment: Things to check : Is SPI listed under `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` ?  If yes, comment it out by putting `#` in front of it.  Can you see spidev under /dev ? Run ` `ls -l /dev/spidev`. It should list out `spidev-0.0` and `spidev-0.1`. For more info read :   https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup.pdf | `configuring SPI` section. Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked everything you told. Everything is working fine. Any idea? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Can you give us connection details ? How are you connecting SPI pins ?

Comment: I just connected MSIO pin of RaspberryPi with its MISO (as told in the tutorial i followed). No other connection.

Comment: You will need to connect SCLK as well. Otherwise there will be no reference clk between master (Rpi) and slave. Why don't you connect all four lines of SPI bus and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry for this question but what should I connect the SCLK to? I am completely new to Raspberry pi and electronics... thanks for the patience. :)

Comment: Pin 23. Have a look at this picture. http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/image/data/tutorial/raspberry-pi/gpio-pinout.jpg

Comment: I know SCLK is pin 23 bu what should I connect it to?

Comment: My bad, vik-y. I didn't notice it's a loop back program. In that case, simply connecting MISO of Rpi with MSIO should do.

Comment: But it's not working.. It's just giving 00 00 00 ... Any idea, suggestions?

Comment: Which kernel are you using ? Can you post output of `uname -a` ?

Comment: If you're running a kernel version `3.18.xx` or later, you might need to add this line `dtparam=spi=on` at the end of `/boot/config.txt` to make SPI device enabled using device tree. Here is a tutorial for doing it. Take a look at it, especially the later half. http://raspi.tv/how-to-enable-spi-on-the-raspberry-pi Hope it helps.

Comment: Done long back. Still facing the same issue. :/

Comment: I'm running out of possibilities. Which Rpi are you using ? 1 or 2 ? I will give it a shot on my setup.

Comment: Works good on my setup. May be your SPI pins are damaged. That's the only possibility left.

Comment: The only possibility is that MISO and MSIO are not connected properly. How are you connecting it ? Can you add a snapshot in your question ?

Comment: I have uploaded the photo. Do check.

Comment: There. Error spotted. That's not it. Here is a reference against 40 pin connector. http://data.designspark.info/uploads/images/53bc258dc6c0425cb44870b50ab30621 What you've connected seems to be Pin 33 and 35. It should be MISO and MOSI. Pin 19 and 21.

Comment: It's working now. I had the sheet of an older model which I was referring to. This seems to be working perfectly fine. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: Cool. :) Glad to know that it solved your problem. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error fixed. Thanks to @dastaan for spotting.

My bad. I was using a 26 pin reference and hence was doing a wrong connection. I used this reference given below and it started working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the SPI struture is not fully initialised.  This error did not use to matter but now causes problems.

```
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,
    };
```

Perhaps try.

```
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr;
memset(&tr, 0, sizeof(tr));
tr.tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx;
tr.rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx;
tr.len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx);
tr.delay_usecs = delay;
tr.speed_hz = speed;
tr.bits_per_word = bits;
```

---

Edited to add.

The wrong gpios are being used.  For the standard SPI device MOSI is pin 19 and MISO is pin 21.

```
           pin  pin
3V3         1    2      5V
0/2 (SDA)   3    4      5V
1/3 (SCL)   5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
21/27      13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
           .......
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. Again the same output. What am I might be missing? Any idea?

Comment: Do /dev/spidev0.0 and /dev/spidev0.1 exist?  Is the spi_bcm2708 or spi_bcm2853 loaded (lsmod)? Are you using the correct gpios?  A photo will be useful to check your connections.

Comment: Yes, they do, checked using ls -l /dev/spidev*   
Yes, lsmod shows spi_bcm2708
I'm connecting the correct pins [Photo Uploaded].
Infact, I tried the same in 2 different pi's, same problem :(
What could be the issue?